# If $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, show $-Q$ is also orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Show that if **$Q$** is an orthogonal matrix then so is **$−Q$**.

I've tried using if $QQ =I$  then

$-I(QQ) = -I(I)$

$(-IQ)Q = -I(I)$ (by associativity)

$Q(-I)Q = -I(I)$ (as $QI = I = IQ$ by definition of the identity)

$Q(-IQ) = -I(I)$ (again by associativity)

$-I(Q(-IQ)) = -I(-I(I))$

$(-IQ)(-IQ) = -(I)-(I)(I)$ (by associativity)

$(-Q)(-Q) = I(I)(I)$ (as $-IQ = -Q$)

$(-Q)(-Q) = I$

Which proves that $Q$ is orthogonal.

I don't know if someone could tell me whether this is valid or if there is a more rigorous way to go about showing this.

Comment: Use the simple fact that $-\mathbf{I}$ is a matrix commuting with all other matrices and $(-\mathbf{I})^2=\mathbf{I}$.

Comment: You forgot the transpose...an orthogonal matrix has $QQ^T=I$

Answer (score 1):

Use the simple fact that $-\mathbf{I}$ is a symmetric matrix commuting with all other matrices and $(-\mathbf{I})^2=(-\mathbf{I})^T(-\mathbf{I})=\mathbf{I}$. Then
$$\mathbf{I} = \mathbf{Q}^T\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{Q}^T\mathbf{I}\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{Q}^T(-\mathbf{I})^T(-\mathbf{I})\mathbf{Q} = (-\mathbf{Q})^T(-\mathbf{Q})$$